# Python XML parse error : SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find the value of 'MS' value using 'company' value.

my code is :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results preview='0'>
<meta>
<fieldOrder>
<field>category</field>
<field>data</field>
</fieldOrder>
</meta>
    <result offset='0'>
        <field k='category'>
            <value><text>company</text></value>
        </field>
        <field k='data'>
            <value><text>MS</text></value>
        </field>
    </result>
    <result offset='1'>
        <field k='category'>
            <value><text>type</text></value>
        </field>
    </result>
    <result offset='2'>
        <field k='category'>
            <value><text>locate</text></value>
        </field>
    </result>
    <result offset='3'>
        <field k='category'>
            <value><text>action</text></value>
        </field>
    </result>
</results>'''


root = ET.fromstring(data)


result = root.find(".//result[field[@k='category'][value/text()='source']]/field[@k='data']/value/text()")

#query_result = root.find(".//result[field[@k='category' and value/text()='author']]")
#result = query_result.find("./field[@k='data']/value/text").text

print(result)
```

but This error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 370, in iterfind selector = _cache[cache_key] KeyError: (".//result[field[@k='category'][value/text()='source']]/field[@k='data']/value/text()",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Tester\Desktop\py_code\test.py", line 41, in <module> result = root.find(".//result[field[@k='category'][value/text()='source']]/field[@k='data']/value/text()") File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 405, in find return next(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces), None) File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 384, in iterfind selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token)) File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 337, in prepare_predicate raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate") SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

What's wrong with the xpath syntax?

I tried the annotation syntax in another way, but the same error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full XPath 1.0 support use lxml not the built-in package of ElementTree; for its (restricted) XPath support see  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax which, I think, suggests one culprit is using e.g. `[value/text()='source']` instead of simple `[value='source']`.

Comment: Fortunately, there was a way to print XML data in a different form, so we solved the problem.
If the same issue occurs, we will try to use the lxml module.
Thank you for the good information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ElementTree's XPath implementation has some missing features related to text nodes. I think it doesn't return text nodes (only elements) and I'm not even sure it supports the `text()` node test (if so, that would explain your error message).

Thankfully, you don't need to use the `text()` node test at all, and you are actually using it in error. Throughout your XPath expression you are referring to text node children of the `value` elements (using `text()`), when you should instead be referring to child nodes which are elements (named `text`). NB none of the `value` elements have text node children; they all contain nothing but a child element named `text`.

Also you can omit the `.//` at the start of your XPath expression because you know that your result elements are all direct children of the root.

Lastly, you say you want to look up the text 'company' and retrieve 'MS', but your XPath expression is actually trying to look up the text 'source'.

Try this:

```xml
result[field[@k='category'][value/text='company']]/field[@k='data']/value/text
```

Because the `value` elements have no text node children, their text value is the same as the text value of their `text` child element, so you could replace `value/text` with just `value`:

```xml
result[field[@k='category'][value='company']]/field[@k='data']/value
```

Comment: I tried, but I get the same error.
Fortunately, there is a way to print the xml data in a different form, so we solved it with that method.
Thanks for your help.